# Exporting from different file/page

Tags: javascript, php, export

I have a problem of exporting data from one page to another

let's say I have `a.php` and `b.php`, I want to have an export button on the `a.php` page but the data is on the `b.php` page 
what function that I can export data from one page to another or is there a script that I can get data to another page.

I want to put it on an excel file

Comment: What kind of data ?

Comment: like Company name, fullname, address etc

Comment: you can include files in php. So you could include b.php into a.php giving you access to the data see w3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: Can i ask for a javascript code? Thank you

Comment: Just put a link or path of b.php page on a.php page and export table data on window load

Comment: @HuzaifaUmair can you give me an example thank you

Comment: You can check my answer i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Html code: on page b.php something like this assign an id to the table

```
<div id="dvData"> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<th>Column One </th>
<th>Column Two</th> 
<th>Column Three</th>
</tr> <tr> 
<td>row1 Col1</td> 
<td>row1 Col2</td> 
<td>row1 Col3</td> 
</tr> <tr> 
<td>row2 Col1</td>
<td>row2 Col2</td> 
<td>row2 Col3</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>row3 Col1</td>
<td>row3 Col2</td>
<td>row3 Col3</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

On page a.php export button or link with anchor tag

```
<a href="b.php"> Export Table data</a>
```

Put this code in b.php

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
 });
```

Comment: If your table contains special characters then put encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html())